# Python replace words and not part of the words when string is a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern of words like this:
`*_you_don't_* think_you_don't_* you_don't_*_* you_don't_know_your_youth`

I want to replace the word 'you' with "we" only when it's a word and not when it's part of the word.

I've tried using the word boundary function but that works only when the text is separated into words and in my case, the pattern is formed using underlines, asterisk etc

```
import re
s = "*_you_don't_* think_you_don't_* you_don't_*_* you_don't_know_your_youth"
re.sub(r'\you\b', 'we', s)
```

In the example above I want the word to look like this:
`*_we_don't_* think_we_don't_* we_don't_*_* we_don't_know_your_youth`

and with the code, I wrote I can't achieve that result.

Comment: `s.replace(' you ', ' we ')` ? (and obviously if not the word is at the beginning or end of the sentence).

Comment: _in my case, the pattern is formed using underlines_ Then couldn't you do a simple substitution of `_you_` to `_we_`?

Comment: Word boundary `\b` doesn't work here because there're no word boundaries between a letter and and underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<=\b|_)you(?=\b|_)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SfJkke/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z] - Matches anything that is a single character

![a-zA-Z] - Anything that is not a single English character

? - One or zero match of pattern

(?<![a-zA-Z])you(?![a-zA-Z]) - This matches "you" if not preceded and 
not followed by a letter
```

**code:**

```
import re
s = "*_you_don't_* think_you_don't_* you_don't_*_* you_don't_know_your_youth"
print re.sub(r'(?<![a-zA-Z])you(?![a-z-Z])', 'we', s)
```

**Output:**

```
*_we_don't_* think_we_don't_* we_don't_*_* we_don't_know_your_youth
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5swwO/1)

Answer (score 0):

With `.replace()` :

```
s = "_you_don't_ think_you_don't_* you_don't__ you_don't_know_your_youth"
string.replace('_you_', '_we_').replace(' you_', ' we_')
```

Output

> "_we_don't_ think_we_don't_* we_don't__ we_don't_know_your_youth"

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what you want, use what you don't want for boundary conditions.

`(?<![^\W_])you(?![^\W_])`

https://regex101.com/r/z2TDXA/1

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way I can think of is using re.sub with backreference groups. You can use the following to achieve your task.

```
re.sub(r'([_|\s])(?:you)(_)', r"\1we\2", s)
```

Here, it the first group in `([_|\s])` and the second group is `(_)`. `(?:you)` is a non-capturing group. In the replacement string \1 and \2 refers to above-mentioned groups. So ultimately your replacement string becomes `<whatever character before you>we<whatever character after you>`